# Merging two objects and then filtering not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two objects as follows. Calling filter method works on individual objects but on a merged object, it is not working...

```
export class ClassName {
  public static urlsA = [
    { url: '/url1', roles: ['Admin', 'User'] } ,
    { url: '/url2', roles: ['Admin', 'Sale'] } ,
  ];

  public static urlsB = [
    { url: '/url11', roles: ['Admin', 'User'] } ,
    { url: '/url22', roles: ['Admin', 'Sale'] } ,
  ];

   public static urls = { ...ClassName.urlA, ...ClassName.urlB };

}
```

I am using the above code in another class like below.

```
  const a = ClassName.urls.filter(f => f.url === 'requiredURL')[0]; // throws Classname.urls.filter is not a function
  const a = ClassName.urlsA.filter(f => f.url === 'requiredURL')[0]; // Working...
  console.error(a);
  console.error(ClassName.urls); // showing in console.
```

Comment: You're destructring in object where as it should be `[ ...ClassName.urlA, ...ClassName.urlB ]`

Comment: `public static urls = [ ...this.urlA, ...this.urlB ];` since you are using it in same class and if used in another class then `public static urls = [ ...ClassName.urlA, ...ClassName.urlB ];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter is a method available on array's not objects, spread into an array not into object

change this

```
public static urls = { ...ClassName.urlA, ...ClassName.urlB };
```

to this

```
public static urls = [ ...ClassName.urlA, ...ClassName.urlB ];
```